# Wordpress positioning

Tags: wordpress

I have a problem with centering an element on my Wordpress site.

with the folowing code :

```
<div id="ss" >
<?php echo do_shortcode( "[smoothslider]" ); ?>
</div>
```

on the site : www.enyx.sk

I added a plugin called "smoothslider". I've tried to change the positioning of the div in css in the following ways:

margin:0 auto;

and also

margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;

Nothing has worked. Could anyone give me an advice about the problem? I can't find out what's wrong.

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you whould put `width` on the div:

```
<div id="ss" style="width: 600px; margin: 0 auto;">
   <?php echo do_shortcode( "[smoothslider]" ); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: actually it makes a lot of sense thank you very much it solved my problem!